# Debbuger not working while running python program

Tags: python, django, debugging, vscode-debugger

When i am trying to debug my django code, the debbuger doesn't stop at any breakpoints. And after sometime all of a sudden it starts working. I am getting this problem in both pycharm and vs code. Are there any settings needed to be changed or is some other things going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your vs code environment in order to compatible with your Django environment. Unless you do it, you can not use debugger in your project. In order to set up the env [look here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_django) . This link will be helpful.

Comment: but the debugger does stop sometimes at the breakpoints